# How to put a public external ip address on Google Cloud VM instance?

Tags: ip, google-cloud-platform, vps, google-compute-engine

I am trying to get a public external IP address for my Compute Engine VM Instance. Most sites are blocked on the default IP address. I tried creating new external IPs but those websites seem to be blocked there too. All I need is an external ip where those websites are not blocked. I have been struggling for two days.
Can I get some help here?

Comment: Where are your connections coming from? , what's the test you're making? can you share an example? or can you share the steps you are following in case that someone in the community wanted to reproduce the error?

Comment: Some web sites choose to block all IP addresses from Google cloud and other cloud providers. Changing it will not help.

Answer (score 5):

First attach external IP to the instance, this can be done on the console -

[GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com) -> `VM Instances` -> "Instance Name" -> `Edit` -> `Network Interfaces`/"edit pencil" -> `External IP` -> `Ephemeral`

The external IP will not show up in the OS layer.  It is a one-to-one NAT by default.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#ephemeraladdress

Then you'll need to create firewall rules to allow traffic.

There are built in `http/https` tags in the VM instance to allow web traffic.  Or you can create custom rules:

Navigate on the GCP console - `VPC Network` -> `Firewall` -> ...

Comment: That's all the settings I have right now. It doesn't give me a public IP address that has websites unblocked

Comment: For end-to-end connectivity it could be any number of things.  It could even be completely non-google related such as your webserver only binding to 127.0.0.1.  There isn't enough information.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the instance you need to say to allow website traffic. On the instance creation screen/dialog you need to check the two boxes "Allow HTTP traffic" and "Allow HTTPS traffic". Then GCP will configure the firewall rules for you.

[VM creation dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7A16.jpg)

You will get an *ephermeral* IP when the instance is created. Then you can choose to have a static one by going to "VPC Network" -> "External IP Addresses", selecting the instance you created and changing the drop-down from Epheremal to Static.

Comment: the thing is, the external ip it generates is blocked by most sites. I need something like, residential ips.